# mysql sql statement too long?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Background Info**
I have 2 versions of what should be the same logic.  The first one works, the second is giving partial results.
I have a function that receives an array of objects.  Each object has an object_id.  For each object in the array, I want to run a sql statement to get more data from the database.

**Sample Code**
In the first example, I loop through the objects one by one and execute the SQL statement.  I start with 1574 records, and I get 1574 results.  However, when I try to make a string with all the ids and then pass that into a SQL "IN" command, I only get 800 or so results. 
Here's part of the code that fails: ( I didn't do a cut and paste of code... just included key sections here)

```
public function getwidgetdetails($widgets)
{
        foreach $widgets as $widget {
               if isset($widget['id']) {
                  $list_of_ids = $widget['id'] . ',' . $list_of_ids;
               }
        }
          //remove the trailing comma
          $list_of_ids = substr($list_of_ids, 0, -1);

          $temparray = explode(",", $list_of_ids);
          print('<BR>temp array count:'.count($temparray) . "<BR>"); // this correctly gives 1574

          $sql = "select * from object where object_id IN(". $list_of_ids. ")";
          $query = $this->db->query($sql);  
          $all_widget_data = $query->result_array();
          print(count($all_widget_data)); -- this gives 800 + records.
}
```

**What I've Tried So Far**

Interestingly, when I try to run the sql statement via command line, I can't paste in the full sql statement without it getting cut off.  I don't know how big the command line buffer is..??

**QUestions**

Is it possible my sql statement is too long?
The other question I have is what's more efficient as far as sql is concerned? 
Is it better to run a separate sql statement for each object?  Or try to combine into one as I'm doing? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) out.  It appears the size of a string within an in clause is limited by the [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) mysql system variable.  It seems the default value is 4MB and can go up to 1GB if necessary.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about that before.  Mine is currently set to 16M... so I think I should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I am not too entirely sure why the result is getting trimmed off (perhaps the query string is too long?).

You could try something like this; where you query the database in chunks?

```
public function getwidgetdetails($widgets)
{
    // Init
    $results = array();

    // Parse Ids
    $list_of_ids = array();
    foreach ($widgets as $widget) {
        if isset($widget['id']) {
            $list_of_ids[] = $widget['id'];
        }
    }

    // Load Data In Chunk
    foreach (array_chunk($list_of_ids, 250) as $ids)
    {
        // Query Db
        $query = $this->db->query(sprintf("select * from object where object_id IN (%s)",
            implode(',', $ids)));

        // Append Result
        $results = array_merge($results, $query->result_array());
    }

    // Finished
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: interesting.  i'll give that a try.  is it more efficient to do it all in one shot vs. running a separate sql statement for each object?  I would imagine so... which is why I started down this road.  But just to double check...

Answer (score 0):

Are your id's consecutive (unlikely)?:

If so, you could try this:

```
$sql = "select * from object where object_id BETWEEN $firstId AND $lastId";
```